# You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. NGINX error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)

When run through `rails s` it works fine but through NGINX I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried to update bundler?

Comment: normal rails server work fine but through Nginx got an error. You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'

Comment: yes but bundler version will be different on both the place. try bundler -v in both the place and paste results here.

Comment: Project - Bundler version 2.0.2 outside of project Bundler version 2.0.2

Comment: What `bundle -v` returns? Make sure you're inside the project folder before running that

Comment: Nginx on its own will not run your Rails server. What are you using to run the app and what do your configs look like? We pretty much need to know exactly how you've set up your web server (which version manager, how it was installed, what web application server (Passenger, Puma, etc), how it was set up, etc.)